# Is there any way to write these if statements more efficiently?

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet where there are a large number of sheets detailing information for each "job" the person filling out the sheet can have. To clean this up, I wrote a script to hide or show the sheets based on which jobs they chose on the first page of the sheet - they can choose up to 3.

The script... works, but I've gotten errors saying it's trying to do too much at once and failed. I'm not exactly a great programmer so how to clean this up is, as of yet, fairly beyond me. I'm not looking for the most efficient, I'm just looking for something that works easily enough.

I googled the problem a few times, but a lot of the solutions I saw didn't seem to exactly fit what I was doing, and involved things like arrays and dictionaries?

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Character Sheet");
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Marauder Abilities");
  var sheet3 = ss.getSheetByName("Warrior Abilities");
  var sheet4 = ss.getSheetByName("Dark Knight");
  var sheet5 = ss.getSheetByName("Gladiator");
  var sheet6 = ss.getSheetByName("Paladin");
  var sheet7 = ss.getSheetByName("Conjurer");
  var sheet8 = ss.getSheetByName("White Mage");
  var sheet9 = ss.getSheetByName("Arcanist");
  var sheet10 = ss.getSheetByName("Scholar");
  var sheet11 = ss.getSheetByName("Astrologian");
  var sheet12 = ss.getSheetByName("Pugilist");
  var sheet13 = ss.getSheetByName("Monk");
  var sheet14 = ss.getSheetByName("Lancer");
  var sheet15 = ss.getSheetByName("Dragoon");
  var sheet16 = ss.getSheetByName("Rogue");
  var sheet17 = ss.getSheetByName("Ninja");
  var sheet18 = ss.getSheetByName("Samurai");
  var sheet19 = ss.getSheetByName("Archer");
  var sheet20 = ss.getSheetByName("Bard");
  var sheet21 = ss.getSheetByName("Machinist");
  var sheet22 = ss.getSheetByName("Summoner");
  var sheet23 = ss.getSheetByName("Thaumaturge");
  var sheet24 = ss.getSheetByName("Black Mage");
  var sheet25 = ss.getSheetByName("Red Mage");
  var sheet26 = ss.getSheetByName("Garlean Pureblood");

  var cell1 = sheet1.getRange('B5');
  var cell2 = sheet1.getRange('C5');
  var cell3 = sheet1.getRange('D5');

  if (cell1.getValue() != "Marauder"||cell2.getValue() != "Marauder"||cell3.getValue() != "Marauder") {
    sheet2.hideSheet();
  }

  if (cell1.getValue() == "Marauder"||cell2.getValue() == "Marauder"||cell3.getValue() == "Marauder") {
    sheet2.showSheet();
  }

  if (cell1.getValue() != "Warrior"||cell2.getValue() != "Warrior"||cell3.getValue() != "Warrior") {
    sheet3.hideSheet();
  }

  if (cell1.getValue() == "Warrior"||cell2.getValue() == "Warrior"||cell3.getValue() == "Warrior") {
    sheet3.showSheet();
  }

  if (cell1.getValue() != "Dark Knight"||cell2.getValue() != "Dark Knight"||cell3.getValue() != "Dark Knight") {
    sheet4.hideSheet();
  }

  if (cell1.getValue() == "Dark Knight"||cell2.getValue() == "Dark Knight"||cell3.getValue() == "Dark Knight") {
    sheet4.showSheet();
  }
```

It goes on from there for all 26 sheets.

Is there an easier way to write this massive thing out?

Could I maybe do

```
if (cell1.getValue() == "Marauder"||cell2.getValue() == "Marauder"||cell3.getValue() == "Marauder") 
{
    sheet2.showSheet();
}
else
{
    sheet2.hideSheet();
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware you could hide sheets with a formula? Sorry, I'm really new with spreadsheets.

Comment: You're correct to sense that your code can be simplified. One strong indicator of this is that, whenever you see repetitive code e.g. `getSheetByName` and your `if` statements, these would be simplified with loops. Arrays and dictionaries will get you away from writing stuff like: `sheet1`, 'sheet2`, .... '`sheetN`.

Comment: For example: `["Marauder","Warrior","Dark Knight","Gladiator"].forEach((role)=> { sheet[role]=ss.getSheetByName(role); });`

Comment: For example: consider hiding *all* the sheets and then unhiding the ones that your users select: `["B5","C5","D5"].forEach((choiceCell) => { choices.push(sheet1.getRange(choiceCel));};` then `choices.forEach((choice)=>{sheet[choice].showSheet();};`

Comment: [Use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Comment: @DazWilkin Google Apps Script hasn't built-in support for arrow functions.

Comment: @rubén good point, thanks. @andrew-pederson in my example replace `forEach((x) => { ... })` with `forEach(function(x) { ... })`

Comment: I don't know all of the requirements, so I can't make a comprehensive suggestion. However, you should consider using [`getSheets()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheets). You should really use [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) instead of calling `getRange()` 3x for cells 1, 2, & 3. Instead of toggling visibility, consider populating existing sheets with data. It would likely be much faster.

Comment: Okay I've done a bit of reading on the arrays and what's going on here, and I'm infuriatingly new, but this is starting to make a -bit- of sense I think.

So:

`["Marauder","Warrior","Dark Knight","Gladiator"].forEach(function(role) { sheet[role]=ss.getSheetByName(role); });`

That's taking each sheet name in the array and... I believe making them variables? That replaces all the var sheet 1 = ss.getSheetByName("Marauder"); stuff I think? Am I close?

Comment: Then the second one looks like it's trying to, put the choices in an array and for each choice (cells B5, C5, and D5), see if they selected any of the sheet names and then show the sheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does it:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sA=["Marauder Abilities","Warrior Abilities","Dark Knight","Gladiator","Paladin","Conjurer","White Mage","Arcanist","Scholar","Astrologian","Pugilist","Monk","Lancer","Dragoon","Rogue","Ninja","Samurai","Archer","Bard","Machinist","Summoner","Thaumaturge","Black Mage","Red Mage","Garlean Pureblood"];
  var cA=["Marauder","Warrior","Dark Knight","Gladiator","Paladin","Conjurer","White Mage","Arcanist","Scholar","Astrologian","Pugilist","Monk","Lancer","Dragoon","Rogue","Ninja","Samurai","Archer","Bard","Machinist","Summoner","Thaumaturge","Black Mage","Red Mage","Garlean Pureblood"];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1=ss.getSheetByName("Character Sheet");
  var cells=sheet1.getRange('B5:D5').getValues()[0];
  var shts=ss.getSheets();
  for(var i=0;i<shts.length;i++) {
    var index=sA.indexOf(shts[i].getName());
    if(index>-1) {
      if(cells[0]!=cA[index] || cells[1]!=cA[index] || cells[2]!=cA[index]) {
        shts[i].hideSheet();
      }
      if(cells[0]==cA[index] || cells[1]==cA[index] || cells[2]==cA[index]) {
        shts[i].showSheet()
      }
    }
  }
}
```